# How do I use HTML/Javascript radio buttons to prompt specific downloads?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to let users choose from five radio buttons that link to a separate file, and on the click of a "Accept & Download" button, they download the file that they selected in the radio button.

This is what I have below. When I click one of the radio buttons and click download, nothing happens.

Javascript:

```
<script>
var isgeorge = document.getElementById('george').checked;
var ismaci = document.getElementById('maci').checked;
var isandre = document.getElementById('andre').checked;
var iscaroline = document.getElementById('caroline').checked;
var isthai = document.getElementById('thai').checked;

var button = document.getElementById('download');
button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
if(isgeorge) {
window.open("gaa2dn-resume.docx");
    }else
if(ismaci) {
window.open("maciresume.docx");
    }else
if(isandre) {
window.open("andreresume.pdf");
    }else
if(iscaroline) {
window.open("cpw6n-resume.pdf");
    }else
if(isthai) {
window.open("tk9kb-resume.pdf");
    }
}
```

HTML in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdqn5.png

Comment: You should be getting the checked values within the function. `isgeorge` and the other variables do not automatically get updated whenever the checkbox is changed.

Comment: So how should it be formatted? Sorry, new to all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting the checked values within the function. `isgeorge` and the other variables do not automatically get updated whenever the checkboxes are changed

So all you have to do is move your variables inside the function

```
function download(){
        var isgeorge = document.getElementById('george').checked;
        var ismaci = document.getElementById('maci').checked;
        //etc etc etc
```

**Demo**

***note:*** since stack snippets dont allow creating new windows the demo just displays a message instead.

```js
var log = document.getElementById('log');
var button = document.getElementById('download');
button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    var isgeorge = document.getElementById('george').checked;
    var ismaci = document.getElementById('maci').checked;
    var isandre = document.getElementById('andre').checked;
    var iscaroline = document.getElementById('caroline').checked;
    var isthai = document.getElementById('thai').checked;
    if(isgeorge) {
        log.innerText = "would have opened: gaa2dn-resume.docx";
        //window.open("gaa2dn-resume.docx");
    } else if(ismaci) {
        log.innerText = "would have opened: maciresume.docx";
        //window.open("maciresume.docx");
    } else if(isandre) {
        log.innerText = "would have opened: andreresume.pdf";
        //window.open("andreresume.pdf");
    } else if(iscaroline) {
        log.innerText = "would have opened: andreresume.pdf";
        //window.open("andreresume.pdf");
    } else if(isthai) {
        log.innerText = "would have opened: tk9kb-resume.pdf";
        //window.open("tk9kb-resume.pdf");
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="george">George</label><input type="radio" name="download" id="george" /><br />
<label for="maci">Maci</label><input type="radio" name="download" id="maci" /><br />
<label for="andre">Andre</label><input type="radio" name="download" id="andre" /><br />
<label for="caroline">Caroline</label><input type="radio" name="download" id="caroline" /><br />
<label for="thai">Thai</label><input type="radio" name="download" id="thai" /><br />

<button id="download">Download</button>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Tried this and it's still not giving me the file when I click the download button. Here's how I implemented it: http://i.imgur.com/LWr5ylY.jpg                    am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: @george Do you have a popup blocker installed in your browser? Note that some like Chrome have internal popup blocker, which you can change in settings

Comment: Nope. No popup blocker.

Comment: @george, do you have a live demo site that can be looked at?

Comment: @george, You have a error on the javascript console for that fiddle, you used `maci`  for the id of two of your radio buttons, it looks like one of them is supposed to be `andre`. Since there was an error the rest of the function does not execute. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke9cn5k0/1/)